# Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm using the InAppBrowser plugin by awesome-cordova-plugins.
After installing it with the commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser
```

as reported on https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser-1

I'm trying to use it in this way:
cloud-account.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {Strings} from "../../Strings";
import {InAppBrowser} from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cloud-account',
  templateUrl: './cloud-account.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cloud-account.page.scss'],

})
export class CloudAccountPage implements OnInit {

    strings = new Strings();
    constructor(private router: Router, private titleService: Title, private iab: InAppBrowser) {
        this.titleService.setTitle(this.strings.CLOUD_ACCOUNT);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CloudAccountPageModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CloudAccountPageModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7498:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7919:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7919:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7919:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7919:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7919:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12077:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3206:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3251:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10034:12)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at core.mjs:23864:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23864:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24165:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
handleError @ core.mjs:8405
next @ core.mjs:24859
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:20868
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:24204
invoke @ zone.js:372
run @ zone.js:134
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:24077
onHandleError @ core.mjs:24204
handleError @ zone.js:376
runGuarded @ zone.js:147
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:1072
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:592
invokeTask @ zone.js:491
invokeTask @ zone.js:1661
globalCallback @ zone.js:1692
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1725
emitEvent @ index-8e692445.js:1279
emit @ index-8e692445.js:1261
selectTab @ ion-tab-bar_2.entry.js:110
TabButton.onClick @ ion-tab-bar_2.entry.js:91
```

So I tried to add it to cloud-account.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CloudAccountPageRoutingModule } from './cloud-account-routing.module';

import { CloudAccountPage } from './cloud-account.page';
import {InAppBrowser} from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    CloudAccountPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [InAppBrowser],
  declarations: [CloudAccountPage]
})
export class CloudAccountPageModule {}
```

Im getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'CloudAccountPageModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?]
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'CloudAccountPageModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?]
    at throwInvalidProviderError (core.mjs:208:15)
    at validateProvider (core.mjs:7730:9)
    at core.mjs:7710:30
    at deepForEachProvider (core.mjs:7742:13)
    at walkProviderTree (core.mjs:7709:13)
    at core.mjs:7574:13
    at core.mjs:4042:76
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.mjs:4042:11)
    at core.mjs:4042:51
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at core.mjs:23864:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23864:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24165:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

Comment: you dont add it in the AppModule, you add it in the module your going to use it in.

Comment: where i have to add it? Which file?

Comment: If your going to use the plugin in Home component, then you add it to the Home Module file.

Comment: It doesn't work, i still get the error: core.mjs:8405 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): `Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'CloudAccountPageModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?]
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'CloudAccountPageModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?]...`

Comment: your asking about InAppBrowserModule, but your posting CloudAccountPageModule....

Comment: I don't understand you. InAppBrowser, as I said in question, is a plugin. I didn't post CloudAccountPageModule.
The problem is that if I want to use the plugin, it tells me that it has to be declared in the provider, but when I declare it as provider in the app.module.ts or in the page where I have to use it as you suggested (i.e. CloudAccountPage) I always get the same error

Comment: read this first before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask